# NSTimer does't work in CMD Project in xCode

Tags: objective-c, timer, nstimer

I have problem with `NSTimer` in Objective-C. This is my source code:
Main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TimerTest.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        TimerTest *timerTest = [[[TimerTest alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

TimerTest.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TimerTest : NSObject {
    NSTimer *_timer;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
- (id) init;
@end
```

TimerTest.m

```
#import "TimerTest.h"

@implementation TimerTest
@synthesize timer = _timer;
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5f 
                                target:self 
                              selector:@selector(tick:) 
                              userInfo:nil 
                               repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) tick: (NSDate *) dt {
    NSLog(@"Tick!  \n");
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.timer = nil;    
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

My program should log "Tick! \n" every 0.5 second. But then my program is finished, xcode console is clear, that's meaning that `NSLog` in 
`-(void)tick:(NSDate *)dt` method didn't work . Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

> My program should log "Tick! \n" every 0.5 second.

No it shouldn't (at least not according to the code you posted).  You need a [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).  Timers only fire as events on run loops.  So, in your main, you need to set one up and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you need an event loop, but you've created a timer, and you haven't scheduled it in said run loop. Instead of:

```
    [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5f 
                            target:self 
                          selector:@selector(tick:) 
                          userInfo:nil 
                           repeats:YES];
```

do this:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(tick:) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
```

I set your code up in the context of a Cocoa application (because it comes with a run loop), executing the TimerTest allocation in the applicationDidFinishLaunching of the delegate, and your code otherwise works.

A couple of other things: The method whose selector is passed to scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:... should be of the form

```
- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)aTimer
```

and when you're done with your timer, just invalidate it:

```
[timer invalidate];
```

though you have to keep a reference to the timer to do this, which it appears you hadn't.